# I use telnet to connect one specific domain name on port 80. it works on personal Ubuntu but not work on Amazon EC2 instance. DNS issue?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, ubuntu-14.04, httpconnection

I have a Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu and a local personal Ubuntu computer. I use the default VPC configuration for my EC2 instance and didn't block any internet traffic from the firewall.

I can telnet Google.com 80 and Ping Google.com on my EC2 instance which means I have internet connection to the outside. I try to run

> `telnet nebraskalegislature.gov 80`

on both machine. It succeed on my own Ubuntu

> `Trying 164.119.9.166...
>   Connected to nebraskalegislature.gov.`

but it time out on my EC2 Instance

> `Trying 164.119.9.166...
>   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

I try to run `dig 164.119.9.166` on both machine.

It has one answer from my own machine but there is no answer on EC2 instance.It looks like a DNS issue

Does anybody can help me this question? Please don't block me again. I am trying to ask a good question.

Comment: I can resolve the DNS from and EC2 Ubuntu, you've changed something somewhere. Check /etc/resolv.conf and make sure it's set to a valid DNS server. Otherwise, you need to check your security groups. Make sure you allow outbound connections on port 53.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I checked the /etc/resolv.conf before and it said nameserver is 172.31.0.2 and search is ec2.internal. I was wandering whether it is a good one or not because I just have two website which are not reachable. Also, the outbound connection in my security groups is open every port to public on this test machine.

Comment: And also means if you do curl on the address, it will response you the HTML string, right?

Comment: @mickzer Thank you for replying. I checked the /etc/resolv.conf before and it said nameserver is 172.31.0.2 and search is ec2.internal. I was wandering whether it is a good one or not because I just have two website which are not reachable. Also, the outbound connection in my security groups is open every port to public on this test machine.

Comment: @mickzer if you use curl on that address, it will response you the HTML string, right?

Comment: The DNS resolver looks fine assuming your VPC has 172.31.something range. The DNS resolver should be the 3rd IP in your VPC. You could always try changing it to Googles DNS 8.8.8.8. And if you curl the address, you should receive a repsonse IF: 1. You have a web server installed and running, 2. Your security groups and NACLs allow it, 3. The instance is in a public subnet, 4. You don't have any software level firewalls blocking port 80 eg. IP tables. Otherwise, you should be good.

Comment: I recommend launching another instance eg. t2.micro temporarily. Try and resolve the address from that new instance.

Comment: @mickzer Hi, I didn't see the comment before. That helps. Could you please talk about how to change from the default DNS to Google 8.8.8.8. Actually, I tried it on the instance itself and it doesn't. I think I have to do that through the web console. But I didn't find the place to do it. You give me good heads up.  How to change the DNS server?

Comment: @mickzer Yeah..I also tried launching a new instance even from another region. It just doesn't work on the new one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I test their website connection on all Amazon EC2 subnets, I think it is their internal bugs. I test two websites which are http://legislature.vermont.gov/ and http://nebraskalegislature.gov/. The result is as following:

For http://legislature.vermont.gov/

1. us-east-1b (fail)
2. us-east-1c (pass)
3. us-east-1d (pass)
4. us-east-1e (fail)

For http://nebraskalegislature.gov/

1. us-east-1b (fail)
2. us-east-1c (pass)
3. us-east-1d (fail)
4. us-east-1e (pass)

For other region like Oregon and California. There are also some issue on their subnet which is not clear`Human beings create machine and also create bugs because of human nature`